# Tracing a phone or car- ionic framework

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, gps, ionic2, android-gps

i need a very fast question... or an explanation..

i want to create a mobile application that it trace for exemple my son phone or my car... so i think that i need a backend where i save some info : identifiers or i dont know what exactly of the phone of my son and my car ....
and a function on the mobile application that it use some api or what exactly that show me the location of that phone or that car ?

anyone can explain for me please what i need axactly ?  (sorry for my english)

Comment: To track the car you will need a gps device, maybe bluetooth, that interfaces to code. To track the phone is easier, you don't need to write an app for that.. Many exist but he has to consent and get the app on his phone. Is this supposed to be secret or does your son know?

Comment: @jhhoff02 you mean to track a phone i have to install an appliccation that send the position to the backend then get that location from the other application ? 
for cars , this gps device what code need from me ? ( javascript ionic )

Comment: Yes he will have to install the application through the app store, you can google search for apps that track phones. For the GPS device you should choose one that can interface to code you know how to use, I'm sure there are GPS devices for every programming language

Comment: @jhhoff02 okey so thank you so much ^^